# Centos 7: Java version for Maven

Tags: maven, centos7, java

I have a open jdk installed on my centos 7. I would like maven to use java 1.8. I wouldn't want to break the machine's java. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Running: `mvn -v`

```
`Maven home: /usr/share/maven
 Java version: 1.7.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el7_3.x86_64/jre
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64", arch: 
 "amd64", family: "unix"`
```

running: `java -version`

```
`openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)`
```

Here is my mvn config

running : `cat /usr/bin/mvn`

```
`#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /usr/share/java-utils/java-functions ] ; then
   . /usr/share/java-utils/java-functions
   set_jvm
   set_javacmd
fi
export M2_HOME="${M2_HOME:-/usr/share/maven}"
export JAVA_HOME; $M2_HOME/bin/mvn "$@"`
```

Running `$yum search java | grep openjdk`

```
`java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64 : OpenJDK Demos
 java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
 java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc.x86_64 : OpenJDK API Documentation
 java-1.6.0-openjdk-src.x86_64 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
 java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java-1.7.0-openjdk-accessibility.x86_64 : OpenJDK accessibility connector
 java-1.7.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64 : OpenJDK Demos
 java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
 java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 : The OpenJDK runtime environment without
 java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
 java-1.7.0-openjdk-src.x86_64 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
 java-1.8.0-openjdk.i686 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-accessibility.x86_64 : OpenJDK accessibility connector
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-accessibility-debug.x86_64 : OpenJDK accessibility connector
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-debug.i686 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment with full debug on
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-debug.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment with full debug on
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64 : OpenJDK Demos
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-demo-debug.x86_64 : OpenJDK Demos with full debug on
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.i686 : OpenJDK Development Environment
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug.i686 : OpenJDK Development Environment with full
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment with
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.i686 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-debug.i686 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment with full
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-debug.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment with full
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc-debug.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation for packages
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc-zip.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation compressed in
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc-zip-debug.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-src.x86_64 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-src-debug.x86_64 : OpenJDK Source Bundle for packages with`
```

Comment: What do you mean by the machines java? Centos doesn't come with Java.

Comment: Whatever is in `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` is modifying your JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: may be this [post](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-maven-on-centos/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ran:
   `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

then:

`alternatives --config javac`

Selected the version required for my project.

Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 2):

1. I doubt you'll "break anything" by changing Maven's JRE to Java 1.8.
2. Run  [alternatives --config java](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment) to see what JVMs are currently installed.  Ideally, if you have both JRE7 and JRE8, you should see both listed.
3. Simply modify your  `/usr/bin/mvn` to point to the desired path.
4. Run `mvn -version` again.  You should see the updated configuration.

Comment: It might even be a good idea to forcibly **uninstall** JRE7 or earlier packages.  They are beyond EOL and undoubtedly have unpatched security holes.

Comment: That's not completely true. It's right that they are beyond the EOL date as announced by Oracle, but OpenJDK 7 is being maintained upstream by the community and is receiving security updates backported from 8 ([example](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk7u-dev/2016-November/010653.html)). If you know of any unpatched vulnerabilities, please inform the maintainers.